# How Can I Duplicate A Item/Record?

Tags: google-app-maker

(Deleted my old question to simplify it. )

I enter data in a table, I then want to make an exact duplicate of that data in a new item/record/row*.

*not sure the proper term.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the slow response. Here is what you should do:

Add a "copy" button in the row. In the onClick on that button, add this code:

```
var createDataSource = widget.datasource.modes.create;
var rowDataSource = widget.datasource;
createDataSource.item.foo = rowDataSource.item.foo;
createDataSource.item.bar = rowDataSource.item.bar;
// And so on for each field
createDataSource.createItem();
```

You could probably make sure of javascript for-in to loop through all the properties of the item in so you don't have to manually specify each record, but I didn't have time to experiment with this.

Edit:

The above code won't show the copied record in the list immediately, because I used row's create data source, instead of the *lists* create data source. Try this instead:

```
var rowDataSource = widget.datasource;
// Instead of using the row  datasource for create, explicitly use the data source of your list.
var listDatasource = app.datasources.NameOfYourListsDataSource;
var createDataSource = listDatasource.modes.create; 

createDataSource.item.foo = rowDataSource.item.foo;
createDataSource.item.bar = rowDataSource.item.bar;
// And so on for each field
createDataSource.createItem();
```

Comment: No worries at all. This worked. Thank you! Is there a way to have the page  (or table) refresh so the new item is displayed? The button currently works, but the new item doesn't appear unless I manually refresh the page.

Comment: Oh that's weird, that might be a bug. I'll update my answer with a likely workaround.

Comment: Ok this one kind of counts as a "feature", but it's something we could definitely improve on. The rows in accordions and lists (and cells in the grid layout) have special data sources which contain only a single item (the item they're displaying). So creating a record using the create data source of a row data source has a different behavior than creating it using the list data source (namely, creating on the row won't add it, because that row is only supposed to show the item it's currently showing) while adding it to the list appends it to the list. Updated the answer, thanks!